# List of Terms/Definitions Text off Page

Tags: lists, line-breaking, margins, paragraphs, text

new to TeX...Most of my document was provided to me as a template but there's something I can't get correct. Trying to make a list of definitions / terms, and on each line it should be like this:

Term (1.9in horizontal space) Definition which goes to the next line if needed, aligned with the beginning of this line.

[image]

My problem is that my file looks like this:

[image]

And my code that produced this:

```
\newcommand\listofdefinitions{%
    \chapter*{\listdefinitionname}

    \begin{tabbing}

        \hskip 1.9in \= \kill
        \par\noindent {Term} \> Here is a very very long definition which should in theory put me on the next line but it's off the page\\
        \par\noindent {Term} \> Definition \\
        \par\noindent {Term} \> This is going to be the very long worded\\\hskip 1.9in / winded definition for some term I need \\
        \par\noindent {Term} \> Definition \\
    \end{tabbing}
}
```

I'm not sure how to fix the right margin such that the text goes to the next line underneath the current definition like in the first picture. The left margin of 1.5in is correct, and the right margin should be 0.5  in (the entire document has this correct with the exception of this page). I have tried using `\usepackage{enumitem}` but unsuccessfully, maybe this package is the best way, and someone can show me how to use it properly?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT - ANSWERED**

Answer (score 1):

ANSWERED VIA REDDIT r/LaTex

The following worked thanks to reddit user u/ProfessorCritique

```
% In preamble:
\usepackage{enumitem}

% In document:
\begin{description}
    [font=\normalfont,leftmargin=1.9in,style=multiline]
    \item[Term]
        Here is a very very long definition which should in
        theory put me on the next line but it's off the page
    \item[Term]
        Definition
    \item[Term]
        This is going to be the very long worded / winded
        definition for some term I need
    \item[Term]
        Definition
\end{description}
```